# How to update applications that were moved from Application folder

Tags: terminal, applications, software-update

All my applications in the `/Applications` folder are sorted in different subfolders, so that I can find them easily.
I know, this is not recommended (see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/76094/organizing-the-mac-os-x-applications-directory)), since the Software Update looks for the app in the `/Applications` folder only when doing the updates, and problems may occur in that case.

That's what happen to me today with the 10.9.3 update: for example, Mail.app has been updated by this update, but in my case, Mail.app were in `/Applications/Internet` (instead of `/Applications`), so now, after the update I've got:

- a non-working Mail.app application in the `/Applications` folder (non-working because it only contains the new updated items of Mail.app)
- the old (working) version of Mail.app in `/Applications/Internet`

I tried to copy (with the `cp -R /Applications/Mail.app /Applications/Internet/Mail.app` command in the terminal) the updated items in the old folder (of course, I made a backup of the Mail.app folder before), but it did not work (it's impossible to run the "new" Mail.app application, it crashes immediately)

So my question is: how could I manually update the Mail.app application (and the other) ?
(and please, don't blame me, like "*it's your fault, you must follow the Apple's rules*" :-) )

Thanks

Comment: I leave the Apps where Apple thinks they should be, and make aliases to them in the spots where they Actually should be. That leaves the App folder in sort of a 'junk drawer' state, but that's how Apple wants it, and they'll make you suffer if you try to neaten it up.

Comment: @Wayfaring Stranger: you're right, that's I will probably do. BUT I do not want to have a 'junk' app folder, I just want a 'clean' app folder...